How to render a component with an inline template?
I am trying to use an inline template to render a component so that I don't have to have HTML in my JS. Also, I don't want a compilation step.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>test component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test component</h1>
    <div id="app">
      <p>mode: [[ mode ]]</p>
      <main-component>
      <template id="mainslot" inline-template>
        <p>
    [[ data ]]
        </p>
      </template>
      </main-component>
    </div>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
          "imports":
          {
              "vue": "vue.esm-browser.js",
              "main_vue": "testcomp.js"
          }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="testmain.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

testcomp.js
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default
{
    name: 'MainComponent',
    setup()
    {
        const data = ref([1,2,3]);
        return {data};
    },
    template:'#mainslot'
};

testmain.js
import { createApp, ref } from 'vue';
import { default as MainComponent } from 'main_vue';

const myapp = createApp(
    {
        components:
        {
            MainComponent  
        },
        setup()
        {
            
            return {
                mode: 'blue'  
            };
        },
    }
);

myapp.config.compilerOptions.delimiters = ['[[', ']]'];

myapp.mount('#app');

When I load the page "mode: blue" is rendered but I get two issue:

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: maincomponent
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

and

[Vue warn]: Property "data" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

Why is the component not doing what I want?

UPDATE
I have changed the tag to <main-component> and now I'm getting a new error!

[Vue warn]: Template element not found or is empty: #mainslot
at <MainComponent>
at <App>


You have to use kebab-case (main-component), see documentation on in-DOM templates for explanation.

@MoritzRingler thank you for your help. I misread that section a dozen times, so I'm glad I finally understand. Unfortunately I have a new problem. I have updated the question.

For now I am using a workaround of not having the template inline
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>test component</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test component</h1>
    <div id="app">
      <p>mode: [[ mode ]]</p>
      <main-component>
      </main-component>
    </div>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
          "imports":
          {
              "vue": "vue.esm-browser.js",
              "main_vue": "testcomp.js"
          }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="testmain.js" type="module"></script>
    <template id="mainslot">
      <p>
        [[ data ]]
      </p>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>

